# SQL Server Decimal(9, 0) vs INT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datatypes

One of our customers uses for some columns the datatype `DECIMAL(18,0)` in his SQL Server 2008R2 database. Because the columns grow quite slowly, he recently proposed to change the datatype to `DECIMAL(5,0)` to regain some storage.

According to the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx), the storage space of the `DECIMAL(5,0)` datatype is, just like the `DECIMAL(9,0)` datatype, 5 bytes. `INT` is 1 byte smaller, but can store everything in the range of -2^31 to 2^31 instead of the -99,999 to 99,999 which `DECIMAL(5,0)` can store. Even the largest `DECIMAL` which fits into 5 bytes (`DECIMAL(9,0)`) can store only integers in the range -999,999,999 to 999,999,999 (which is less than half of the range `INT` offers in 4 bytes).

I can think of two "benefits" of using `DECIMAL` over `INT`:

- The ability to add scale afterwards, without using more storage space
- The ability to scale the precision up to 38 digits, without altering data type

but these aren't real benefits in my opinion:

- Adding scale to integers does only make sense in very few cases (in most cases where scale does make a difference, it could also be added beforehand)
- SQL Server sees every precision / scale combination as a different data type, so the datatype isn't left alone when increasing the precision or scale.

This makes me wonder: what is the added benefit of a `DECIMAL(5,0)` datatype for integers?

Comment: One benefit can be the five digit limit.  But I wonder how much storage space can you spare with such a change.

Comment: IMO, if you just need to make sure the column values fall within a range, use a check constraint. I think the only consideration here would be if there's the possibility of this column requiring fractional values in the future.

Comment: If they're worried about storage space, they're better suited using compression than this. There is no tangible benefit to using decimal(x, 0) instead of int/bigint.

Comment: Another difference between `decimal(x,0)` and an integer type shows itself in arithmetical division. If you divide an int by an int, you get an int. If you divide a decimal(x,0) by an int, you get a decimal(x+6,6).

Comment: @AndriyM, I think this is the greatest benefit. Rephrase it into an answer instead of a comment and I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: Thank you for the offer. @Chris Chubb has already referred to that point in his answer, so I'm not posting mine until I find something to balance/complement it with. If that's the single aspect that you care most about, though, feel free to post your own answer. There may be additional value to your answer if you explain why that aspect is so important in your particular case.

Comment: I got a legacy system where those Decimal(18,0) are used for **Ids**. In this case I guess it's not a good practice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that there are no real benefits in terms of **storage** space as long as you are comparing DECIMAL(9, 0) vs INT or DECIMAL(18, 0) vs BIGINT. (Within a single byte.)

In terms of processing, like @Andriy says the DECIMAL will naturally divide into a type that doesn't lose the fractional part, if that's important to you.

On the other hand, working with native INT types is **much** faster from a numerical standpoint if you are doing a lot of SUM()s or comparisons (such as searching on the values) as they are pipelined more efficiently by the CPU. An int comparison is two assembly opcodes (MOV, CMP) but any decimal comparison will be many, many more.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but a processor doesn't have any knowledge of datatypes. So one datatype of 4 bytes, is compared just as fast as another datatype of 4 bytes. Can you show (with a repeatable performance test, for example) that there's a performance hit in using `DECIMAL(9, 0)` instead of an `INT`?

Comment: I thought I could, but I'll admit that my tests are inconclusive. Perhaps SQL is doing an optimization to reduce the problem to integer math. My testbed:
`
--Int comparison
SET @StartTime = SYSDATETIME()
WHILE (@CounterINT < @SizeINT) SET @CounterINT = @CounterINT + 1
PRINT 'INT took ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEDIFF(millisecond, @StartTime, SYSDATETIME())) + ' milliseconds'

--Decimal
SET @StartTime = SYSDATETIME()
WHILE (@CounterDEC < @SizeDEC) SET @CounterDEC = @CounterDEC + 1
PRINT 'DEC took ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEDIFF(millisecond, @StartTime, SYSDATETIME())) + ' milliseconds'
`

Comment: I think SQL Server optimizes something there indeed. Despite the optimization `DECIMAL` still takes usually somewhat longer (at least on my development system). In a run of 10 tests around 51 ms DEC vs. 46 ms INT.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there **will be no benefits** in terms of storage space.

If you client is concerned that you values will be bigger than 2^32-1 (maximum positive value integer can store) then you should consider moving to **BigInt** - with is 64 bits (**8 bytes)**.